# How to set elastic alert on amazon elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, alert

I've been looking for a tutorial that I can get alerts from amazon elasticsearch.
I'm using metricbeat in my server instance to collect logs everything is fine but now I have to find a way to send alert for my memory and cpu, I read something about elastic alert to send alert to e-mail or slack but I don't know how to use it on amazon elasticsearch.
If anybody has a tutorial that help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need x-pack to be able to configure watchers to send email or Slack alerts. But, AWS Elasticsearch does not offer x-pack features. For this exact reason we moved away from AWS Elasticsearch to Elastic Cloud and we couldn’t be happier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer that helped me to understand how it works